# Python: Creating Multiple Text file from a column in CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, text

I have a CSV  file with 3 columns Imagename , image_size and class. I want to create multiple text files reading the CSV with Imagename as filename and image_size and class as  file content.

I need to loop through the Imagename and if the Imagename is similar the  append the corresponding image_size and class in a single txt file.

If the Imagename is different, create another txt file and append it's corresponding image_size, class.

Below is the sample csv:

```
Image_name   image_size  class
Img_0001     150         brightness 
Img_0001     153         Noise
Img_0001     170         skewness
Img_0002     132         brightness
Img_0002     188         Noise
Img_0002     191         skewness
Img_0003     159         brightness
Img_0003     111         Noise
Img_0003     170         skewness
```

The filename I need to create:

```
Img_0001.txt
```

and the  file content within the txt file :

```
150         brightness 
153         Noise
170         skewnes
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading your CSV file with `pd.read_csv` you can create txt files for each unique `Image_name` entry in the following way.

```py
for image in df.Image_name.unique():
    fileName = image +".txt"
    file = open(fileName,"w+") #creating a txt file if not already exists
    
    #adding rows for each unique image name 
    for row in df[df.Image_name==image].values:
        file.write(f"{row[1]} {row[2]}") #writing to txt file
```

Here `df.Image_name.unique()` returns all unique values under `Image_name` column. Then we runs loop for each name and retrieve info from the CSV and add those to txt files.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the CSV file with `pd.read_csv` and then use `.groupby()` to *"split"* the dataframe to multiple dataframes according the `Image_name`. For example:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv")

for filename, g in df.groupby("Image_name"):
    g.to_csv(filename + ".txt", index=False)
```

Creates `Img_000*.txt` files.